# How to delete "," at the end of the program python set

Tags: python, list, set

```py
l = {"John","Evan"}

for i in l:
    print(i,end=",")
```

How to get python to output: `jhon,evan` not: `jhon,evan,` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` strings (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to achieve this result:

`print(','.join(l))`

Will print: `jhon,even`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a list instead of a set, you could iterate by index and then prepend a comma starting with the second element.

```py
l = {"John", "Evan"}
names = list(l)
for idx in range(len(names)):
    if idx > 0:
        print(",", end="")
    print(names[idx], end="")
    # John,Evan
```